# Numpy value assignment by indexing or slicing, duplicate memory allocation?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-slicing

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0.,0.,0.,0.])
b = a
c = a
d = a.copy()

a[0] = 2.
print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
print(d)
```

The result is `[2. 0. 0. 0.]` for ALL a,b and c, which is very weird. d still correctly retains the values as zeros though.

Is it an intended behavior?

Comment: Yes it is an intended behaviour as all of `a`, `b` and `c` share memory and can be easily verified by simply checking `a is b` etc.

Comment: Why is it weird?  That's normal Python behavior.  `b` is `a` as is `c`.  They all reference the same array object.  `d` is  a copy, the others are not.

Comment: It is intended behavior, `a`, `b`, `c` all point to the same underlying array's memory location, while `d` points to a new copy of `a` when it looked like `np.array([0.,0.,0.,0.])` since you [`numpy.ndarray.copy`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.copy.html#numpy.ndarray.copy).

Comment: thank you, could you post as an answer so I could accept it?

Comment: @hpaulj Not having a rich Python experience, and coming from MATLAB, it looks totally weird to me...

Comment: My MATLAB experience is old (though occasionally I'll fireup an Octave session).  Yes assignment there does make a copy.  Python on the other hand is object-oriented from the ground up, so variables are just names used to reference objects.  Copying has to be explicitly done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is an intended behaviour as all of `a`, `b` and `c` are essentially the same python object in memory and can be easily verified by simply checking `a is b` etc.

Only `d` is assigned a separate copy of `a` in memory.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([0.,0.,0.,0.])
>>> b = a
>>> c = a
>>> d = a.copy()
>>> a is b
True
>>> b is c
True
>>> c is a
True
>>> a is d
False
```

Comment: It's more than share memory.  They are the same Python object.  Sharing memory is a better description of a numpy `view`.  That's a new array object, but with a shared data buffer (the underlying 1d `c` array where values are stored).